# Swift execute closure on main thread trough custom operator

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, closures

Apparently Xcode doesn't let me modify the UI (iOS) from a background thread. I have to type:

```
let res = somethingReturningaString()
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.txtError.text = res!
})
```

My idea was: 'hey, let's simplify my life and define a custom operator, so I can type something like:'

```
prefix operator ~> {}

prefix func ~> (closure: ()-> ()) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
//usage example
~> {self.txtError.text = res!}
```

Apparently the operator of type '()' cannot be applied to '()->()'
Does anybody know how to declare this to get this working?

Comment: remove the whitespace between the `~>` and `{self.txtError.text = res!}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swift compiler got a little confused there. You must not ever separate a unary operator from its operand, meaning **there must not be a whitespace** in between.

Consider the following example code

```
let k = 12
~> {
    self.txtError.text = res!
}
```

Swift now expects `~>` to be a binary operand because there is a whitespace.

> binary operator '~>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and '() -> ()'

If you insert a `;` after the first line:

```
let k = 12;
~> {
    self.txtError.text = res!
}
```

You receive something a little bit more helpful:

> Unary operator cannot be separated from its operand

Which simply means that there must in fact be no whitespace.

## Fix

Remove the whitespace:

```
~>{ self.txtError.text = res! }
```

Comment: @Seneca luk2302 perfectly answers the question and perfectly shows why 'custom operator' is not always the best, what to do. why not to use in this situation something like `func updateUI(closure: ()-> ()) { dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure) }`?

Comment: I fully agree with @user3441734 that using a custom operator in this situation might actually not be the correct choice in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, custom operator might not be the best way to go here... I think I got a little bit carried away